# What is the status of Catholics who reject Vatican II? Are they considered heretics?

Tags: catholicism, heresy, vatican-ii

Are Catholics opposing Vatican II considered heretics (by the Roman Catholic Church)?

Comment: Could you tell us a bit more about what *exactly* you want to find out, why it's important to you, what you already know on the subject etc?

Comment: @waxeagle It seems to me that if people think Vatican II is not in line with prior doctrine, they are in opposition to the official r. catholic church teaching. I wonder what officials have to say about those people. I don't know much more. As to importance: Is curiosity not enough a reason?

Comment: Generally it's *better* to ask questions you have a stake in and that you've spent some time looking into.

Comment: @waxeagle. "Have a stake in"? That is rubbish. This site is also for the 'curious'. If you want to change the rules of the site go for it. Until then, stay away if you do not like a question.

Comment: @gideonmarx have you read the help center? "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."

Comment: @gideonmarx I found a relevant [meta discussion](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/based-on-actual-problems-that-you-face). I think the main takeaway for us is, "If you can walk away from your question and not care too much about the answer," that's a good indication that it's not a good fit. Otherwise ask away. "Make us believe your question is important to you, and to anyone else who will ever read it."

Comment: @waxeagle I think it's a fine question. I'd prefer a few more details showing that the OP has attempted some research effort of his own, but it's still a good question to me.

Comment: Related questions: [What is the Difference between a Heretic and a Schismatic, according Catholic and Orthodox tradition?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/26733) | [For Catholics who object to Vatican II, what are the key issues?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/32008) | [Is the Society of St. Pius X schismatic or not?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/22900)

Comment: What do you mean by 'stand'? Status?

Comment: @protestants, this is really a good question because there appears to be a lot of deceit in those sedevacantist movements and this might be all the person asking the question even _can_ know about what they're talking about.

Comment: @curiousdannii I guess, edited.

Comment: @fredsbend Thanks, that makes me think my question is a duplicate, but it's rather hard to see without considering all three of the questions. The question that raised my question was one similar to the second question you cited, but I don't remember it referencing that Society. Maybe it is worth making an answer comprising key points of the answers to the related questions, to get them into one place? For example, one of the answers to the second question states that "The groups who reject Vatican II,[..] are [..] mostly of people attached to the group called SSPX".

Comment: Can somebody answer the question? It is relevant for reasons you may not understand but that makes it no less important.

Comment: @kutschkem Could a link be provided to this "Vatican II" documentation?

Comment: @Onlyheisgood. You mean like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Vatican_Council ? Sources can be found there. Note that, for the purpose of this question, I don't really care too much about the outcome of that council, just the question what the Church officially thinks of/ says about those who reject the teachings of an official council. To me as an outsider this seems like rejection of the church authorities, and my assumption is that this is not taken lightly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It is always good to start with definitions.**

*Heresy*<sup>1</sup> ≡ is the obstinate post-baptismal denial of some truth which must be believed with divine and catholic faith, or it is likewise an obstinate doubt concerning the same. [cf. [CCC 2809](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p3s2c1a1.htm#2089).]

<sup>1. Fuller treatment here: [Heresy | New Advent](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/07256b.htm).</sup>

The chief things which God has revealed, and therefore to be believed, are contained in the Apostles' Creed. [cf. [Penny Catechism, 13](http://www.catholictreasury.info/catechism/cat2.php).]

An example of a a heresy is Arianism, the first heresy that gained a strong footing in the Church and seriously endangered its very nature and existence. Arius bluntly asserting that Christ was not God like the Father, but a creature made in time.

---

**Next it would be good to say what the council was all about from the Church's perspective.**

The future Pope Benedict XVI [now Pope Emeritus], when he was still prefect of the Congregation for the Doctrine of the Faith, said in an address, given July 13, 1988, in Santiago, Chile before that nation's bishops, that, *the truth is that this particular council defined no dogma at all, and deliberately chose to remain on a modest level, as a merely pastoral council.*<sup>2</sup>

<sup>2. cf. [Library: Cardinal Ratzinger's Remarks Regarding the Lefebvre Schism - Catholic Culture](http://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/view.cfm?recnum=3032).</sup>

Therefore from the Church's perspective pre and post Vatican II, there has been no change in the truths to be believed.

---

**Continuing to how the Church interprets the Council.**

Carol Glatz in [a post](http://www.catholicherald.co.uk/news/2012/11/30/prefect-of-the-cdf-says-seeing-vatican-ii-as-a-rupture-is-heresy/) on Friday, 30 Nov 2012 in the Catholic Herald reported Archbishop Gerhard Müller saying that *what Pope Benedict XVI has termed “the hermeneutic of reform, of renewal in continuity” is the “only possible interpretation according to the principles of Catholic theology”.*

In the article, the Archbishop continued:

> “Outside this sole orthodox interpretation unfortunately exists a
>   heretical interpretation, that is, a hermeneutic of rupture, [found]
>   both on the progressive front and on the traditionalist” side.

Note: The Archbishop's reflections are [here](http://www.doctrinafidei.va/muller/rc_con_cfaith_doc_20121128_riflessioni-muller_it.html) in Italian.

---

### Therefore Answering

According to Archbishop Muller, there are "progressives" and "traditionalists" who refuse the Council, who do not have the unique orthodox interpretation of the Council which Pope Benedict XVI termed "the hermeneutic of reform in continuity". Theirs is an interpretation of "discontinuity and rupture" and the Archbishop terms this interpretation as a **heretical interpretation**.